# Plotly 4.8.0 Not Working in RStudio 1.1.383

Tags: windows, rstudio, plotly

I have installed **Plotly** in **Rstudio** successfully. My environment is:

- Windows 10 version 1803
- Rstudio version 1.1.383
- Plotly version 4.8.0

However when I try to use it, I receive an error message:

```
plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = "scatter")
```

> No scatter mode specifed: Setting the mode to markers 
>   
> Read more about this attribute -> https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter-mode
>   
> Error in `arrange_impl(.data, dots)` : 
>   Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
>   Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the link that you are geeting with the error, then it says:

> mode (flaglist string) 
>   **Any combination of "lines", "markers", "text" joined with a "+" OR "none". 
>   examples: "lines", "markers", "lines+markers", "lines+markers+text", "none"** 
>   Determines the drawing mode for this scatter trace. If the provided `mode` includes "text" then the `text` elements appear at the coordinates. Otherwise, the `text` elements appear on hover. If there are less than 20 points and the trace is not stacked then the default is "lines+markers". Otherwise, "lines".

I get the same error but the graph appears. Check the `Viewer` window in stead of `Plots` window.